# I'm getting this error "The value of the local variable driver is not used" while launching chrome with selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation

Here , is the code below. I cannot launch chrome as trying to learn to selenium with java.

```
`package SeleniumBasics;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

 public class ChromeTest
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  }
}`
```

I'm trying to launch chrome and expect to successfully open it so that i can proceed with further automation.

Comment: Can you share the error trace which you may be seeing in the console?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided looks correct, but there are a few things you can check to ensure that Chrome launches successfully:

Make sure that you have downloaded the correct version of the ChromeDriver executable that matches your installed version of Chrome browser. You can download the latest version of ChromeDriver from the official website: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Check the path of your ChromeDriver executable file. In your code, you have set the path to `"C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.exe"`. Ensure that this is the correct path where you have saved the ChromeDriver executable.

Make sure that you have added the Selenium Java libraries to your project's classpath. You can download the Selenium Java libraries from the official website: https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

If you are still facing issues with launching Chrome, try adding the following line of code before creating the ChromeDriver instance: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");`. This will enable verbose logging, which can help identify the root cause of any issues with launching Chrome.

Once you have checked these things, try running your code again. If Chrome still does not launch successfully, you may need to investigate further by checking the error messages that are displayed in the console or logs.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are not using `driver` in your code that you have used to initialize the `ChromeDriver`. You have to just the use the `driver` to get rid of this error. Add the below line in the end of your code.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

***Note:-*** `https://www.google.com` is just a sample URL, you have to use the one that you are using.